# Implementing dirpath(3p) and fdirpath(3p) functions

Tags: c, file-system, posix

I'm implementing a `dirpath` and `fdirpath` functions, which allow to retrieve path from the directory handle (or its descriptor). This can be useful e.g. if one needs to implement some functions like `openat(3)` on systems which lack similar functions, but have `fork(3)`, `mmap(3)` and pthreads. I'd like to know your opinions, suggestions on how to improve these functions, proposals, advice and even remarks. The function shall remain as portable as possible (by portability I mean POSIX).

**Source code**

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>


static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

size_t fdirpath(int fd, char *buffer, size_t size)
{
    int mfd = -1;
    pid_t pid = 0;
    int status = 0;
    size_t msize = 0;
    char *mdata = NULL;
    char mpath[] = "/tmp/dirpath/XXXXXX";
    int const mflags = MAP_SHARED;
    int const mprot = (PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE);
    size_t *total = NULL;

    if ((fd == -1)
    ||  ((buffer == NULL) && (size != 0))
    ||  ((buffer != NULL) && (size == 0))) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return (size_t)-1;
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if (mkdir("/tmp/dirpath", 0755) == -1) {
        if (errno != EEXIST) {
            return (size_t)-1;
        }
    }
    if ((mfd = mkstemp(mpath)) == -1) {
        return (size_t)-1;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    /* Create a temporary shared file */
    msize += sizeof(size_t);
    msize += size;
    if (ftruncate(mfd, (off_t)msize)) {
        status = errno;
        close(mfd);
        unlink(mpath);
        errno = status;
        return (size_t)-1;
    }
    if ((mdata = mmap(NULL, msize, mprot, mflags, mfd, 0)) == MAP_FAILED) {
        status = errno;
        close(mfd);
        unlink(mpath);
        errno = status;
        return (size_t)-1;
    }
    total = (size_t*)mdata;
    mdata += sizeof(size_t);
    if (buffer != NULL) {
        memcpy(mdata, buffer, size);
    }
    mdata -= sizeof(size_t);

    /* Determine directory path in child process */
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
        size_t len = 64;
        char *path = NULL;
        void *temp = NULL;

        if (fchdir(fd) == -1) {
            exit(errno);
        }
        total = (size_t*)mdata;
        while (temp == NULL) {
            temp = path;
            path = realloc(path, len);
            if (path == NULL) {
                free(temp);
                exit(ENOMEM);
            }
            memset(path, 0, len);
            temp = getcwd(path, len);
            if (temp == NULL) {
                if (errno != ERANGE) {
                    free(path);
                    exit(errno);
                }
                temp = NULL;
                len *= 2;
            }
        }
        *total = strlen(path);
        if (buffer != NULL) {
            mdata += sizeof(size_t);
            size = ((*total > size) ? size : *total);
            memcpy(mdata, path, size);
        }
        free(path);
        exit(0);
    } else if (pid == -1) {
        status = errno;
        close(mfd);
        unlink(mpath);
        errno = status;
        return (size_t)-1;
    }

    /* Acquire shared data and store it */
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    if (status != 0) {
        close(mfd);
        unlink(mpath);
        munmap(mdata, msize);
        errno = status;
        return (size_t)-1;
    }
    if (buffer != NULL) {
        mdata += sizeof(size_t);
        size = ((*total > size) ? size : *total);
        memcpy(buffer, mdata, size);
        mdata -= sizeof(size_t);
    }
    size = *total;
    if (close(mfd) == -1) {
        status = errno;
        unlink(mpath);
        munmap(mdata, msize);
        errno = status;
        return (size_t)-1;
    }
    if (unlink(mpath) == -1) {
        status = errno;
        munmap(mdata, msize);
        errno = status;
        return (size_t)-1;
    }
    if (munmap(mdata, msize) == -1) {
        return (size_t)-1;
    }

    /* Perform cleanup routines */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if (rmdir("/tmp/dirpath") == -1) {
#if defined(ENOEMPTY) && (ENOEMPTY != EEXIST)
        if ((errno != EEXIST) && (errno != ENOEMPTY)) {
            return (size_t)-1;
        }
#else
        if (errno != EEXIST) {
            return (size_t)-1;
        }
#endif
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return size;
}


size_t dirpath(DIR *dir, char *buffer, size_t size)
{
    int fd = -1;

    if (dir == NULL) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return (size_t)-1;
    }
    if ((fd = dirfd(dir)) == -1) {
        return (size_t)-1;
    }
    return fdirpath(fd, buffer, size);
}
```

**Usage**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    size_t size = 0;
    DIR *dir = NULL;
    char *buffer = NULL;

    /* Opening a directory */
    dir = opendir(".");
    if (dir == NULL) {
        perror("dirpath");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Calculating size */
    size = dirpath(dir, NULL, 0);
    if (size == (size_t)-1) {
        perror("dirpath");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Allocating memory */
    buffer = malloc(size);
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        perror("dirpath");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Determining path */
    if (dirpath(dir, buffer, size) == (size_t)-1) {
        perror("dirpath");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    closedir(dir);
    free(buffer);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Notes**

I've tried to be as POSIX-compatible as it is possible; thus I didn't use `MAP_ANON`: though it's usage is pretty common, it is not included in POSIX standard (what a pity!).

I've used `fork(3)` to let functions work in the multithreaded environment: `getcwd(3)` may yield inappropriate results when `chdir(3)` is called in the different threads. Using a mutex was the very first idea that came to my mind, but I also wanted to try to avoid situations where someone else is calling `chdir`.

I've used a temporary directory since it seemed to better generate a unique filename for a temporary mmap'ed file. However, I'm unsure if it is correct, since function will fail right after unsuccessfull call to `mkdir(3)`, which seems to be not very good decision. Perhaps it's better just to stick to `mkstemp(3)` without any directory.

`mmap(3)` is used here; perhaps it's better to stick to `shm*` functions? Or pipes? The point is to share the data between parent and child after `fork(3)`, I'm not sure if `mmap(3)` is actually the best thing here (especially since I cannot use `MAP_ANON` due to portability reasons, so I have to `unlink(3)` file).

Answer (score 2):

> I've used fork(3) to let functions work in the multithreaded environment: getcwd(3) may yield inappropriate results when chdir(3) is called in the different threads.

*This* problem is solved by introducing more problems. It is very unsafe to `fork`  multithreaded program in the first place (see [this blog post](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them) for details). I don't know how to solve the path resolution problem in absence of `*at()` calls in a sane way. Maybe, I'd resort to running a path resolution daemon with a unix domain sockets to communicate open descriptors.

In any case, `mmap` backed up by the actual file doesn't sound right.

Comment: What's an amazing post! Thank you very much, I've never thought about such kind of problems. Well, actually functions can use platform-dependent solutions (e.g. `readlink` on `/proc/PID/fd/XXX` on Linux and Cygwin, `F_GETPATH` for OS X, etc.) and then fallback to current behaviour. However, on mentioned systems there are already `*at()` calls, if I recall correctly.
Actually neither I think that using `mmap` with the real file is a good idea. The only reason why I do it is that POSIX doesn't support `MAP_ANON` (there is a proposal to bring this flag in the next standard though).

Comment: What do you think about just using mutexes? That's the first idea that came to my mind, but I also wanted to try to avoid situations where someone else is calling `chdir`.